# Bookmarks for multiple layers

Tags: qgis, bookmarks

For a project I'm working with QGIS, I have multiple raster layers with interesting points and features.

My final goal for the project is to give a person who is not familiar with GIS but who would like to see those interesting points and features easy access to this data. My idea was to use bookmarks, so people can select a point they would like to see and the program selects automatically the right zoom and place. It works kind of what I expected but when I select a bookmark with the wrong layer it just zooms to the right place but it doesn't change the layer.

Is there a option or plugin that I could use for this problem or do I have to make this by myself.

Comment: Are you sure having other users using QGIS is the most effective way to show them these interesting points? If the goal is to have pre-defined views of certain layers at certain locations, wouldn't a series of static maps be easier?

Comment: At my job, we hand out kml/kmz for use in Google Earth to all people who don't know their way around QGis. It's easier to use than QGis, and the zooming and bookmarking is already there.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that using bookmarks in QGIS. Bookmarks' goal is panning and zooming to pre-defined extent. Carrying out that by programming/plugin via bookmarks doesn't make any sense, too. Because, bookmarks don't hold any layer information, like 'which layer was selected when bookmark created'. 
[image: Sample information of QGIS bookmark]